# difference between 2 string holding Cisco device's config

Tags: python

I have 2 variables, config1 and config2 holding the running config of a Cisco device at 2 different points in time.

Sample running config:

```
version 12.3
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname retail
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable password cisco123
!
username jsomeone password 0 cg6#107X
aaa new-model
!
aaa group server radius rad_eap
    server 10.0.1.1 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
!
aaa authentication login eap_methods group rad_eap
aaa session-id common
ip subnet-zero
ip cef
!
vpdn enable
    vpdn-group 1
    request-dialin
    protocol pppoe
!
interface dialer 1
    ip address negotiated
    ppp authentication chap
    dialer pool 1
    dialer-group 1
!
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
    ip nat inside source list 1 interface dialer 0 overload
    ip classless (default)
    ip route 10.10.25.2 0.255.255.255 dialer 0
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.1.1 10.0.1.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.2.1 10.0.2.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.3.1 10.0.3.10
!
ip dhcp pool vlan1
   network 10.0.1.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.0.1.1 
!
```

config1 holds the default config and config2 holds the config after doing a test. Ultimately, config2 should be the same as config1.

What I need is a way to find a "diff" between config2 and config1 (config2-config1). Something that I get from websites like https://text-compare.com/ which shows side-by-side comparison.

Comment: You might start by checking out [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)

Comment: Check also https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch. If I remerber there is a html output.